# Copy all the Database - Tables,Stored Procedures into a file and save on a flash disk

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ssms

Is there any way to copy all the Database - Tables,Stored Procedures
into a file and save on a flash disk?

I want to be able to open it from anywhere.

Also is there anyway that I can pass the permission while I do so?

Comment: SQL Server != MySql. You need to specify which

Comment: I took it out.... but how do I save all the DB into a file??

Comment: the general answer is yes, you can save any database data on your hard drive(export it) and then import it in another database server but as @JonTirjan mentioned, you have to first mention which database engine you are using, so we can help you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mySql database with name "mydatabase" to backup you have to execute following code from a command line:

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > mydatabase.sql
```

and after that put your password

To restore it on another server, copy mydatabase.sql and execute from the command line:

```
mysql -u root -p mydatabase < mydatabase.sql
```